# Open a new Activity with chosen Fragment on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onclick, android-button

this is what I want to achieve:

- I'm in Activity A with couple options to choose from (buttons)
- after clicking any of them, I want to be taken to Activity B
- Activity B should contain a constant part (audio) and a Fragment with image and text, depending on the button you choose in Activity A.

Is it achievable? I tried to both startActivity and getSupportFragmentManager (etc.) as my onClick method but with no use, maybe there's another way?

Comment: let us to see your code to understand your situation clearly

Answer (score 0):

In activity B create a method (static in java, companion in kotlin) to create an intent:

```
companion object {
    const val ARG_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD = "argFragment"

    fun newIntent(context:Context, fragmentTagToLoad:String): Intent {
        return Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java).apply {
            putString(ARG_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD, fragmentTagToLoad)
        })
    }
}
```

Then, in activity A you can use this intent to start activity B.

```
myButton?.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(ActivityB.newIntent(this, SomeFragmentToLoad.ARG_TAG))
}
```

Then, again in activity B you will receive this argument in the intent, so that you can handle it. It is typically done inside onCreate():

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val fragmentTagToLoad = intent.getStringExtra(ARG_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD) ?: ""

    if(fragmentToLoad.isNotEmpty() {
        // Use fragment manager to load fragment into container.
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, in activity B you can use the argument to load the desired fragment using a (usually support) fragment manager.

Of course you should define ARG_TAG as a String constant inside SomeFragmentToLoad.